# A better way to map data to a column in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have several large data frames that I need to merge, and sometimes add a unique identifiable column in order to merge them. I use this approach which works, but seems to take a long time. Basically, using `dplyr`, I grab the `distinct` returns of a variable, then `mutate` a new variable to each, then `merge` that variable back to the original dataframe. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
df <- tibble(
  x = rep(LETTERS, 10)
)


df %>% 
  distinct(x) %>% 
  mutate(y = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
  right_join(df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `match`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(y = match(x, unique(x)))
```

---

or with `factor`

```
df %>% 
    mutate(y = as.integer(factor(x, levels = unique(x))))
```

---

Or with `group_indices`

```
df %>%
   mutate(y = group_indices(., x))
```

Comment: Thanks! group_indices seems to be the fastest and cleanest. It's perfect @akrun!

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't specify if you needed dplyr, here's a data.table approach:

```
setDT(df)[, y := .GRP, by=x]
```

or in base R, simply

```
df$y = as.integer(factor(df$x))
```